# Find IOCTL number in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, header-files, ioctl

I see into header file

```
#define IOCTL_MAGIC 'A'
#define IOCTL_NAME _IOWR(IOCTL_MAGIC, 2, ioctl_param)
```

How can I know that is the ioctl number of `IOCTL_NAME` ?

Comment: If you want to know which numerical value that is, you could just print it or look at preprocessor output.

Comment: @Gerhardh I can't recompile that code, only look at binary and in that decleration

Comment: That's not enough information to get the value you want. Need at least the definition of `_IOWR` as well. That is, find all the macro definitions and expand them on a piece of paper. Or put them into a file and run the C preprocessor on that file  (assuming you are allowed to do that).

Comment: @kaylum `_IOWR` is define into `ioctl.h` no ? there is not costume implementation for that  , no ?

Comment: I didn't say anything about where it is or isn't defined. You asked how to work out the final value. I explained the way to do it - get all the macros and expand them. What specific difficulty do you have with that if you know where the macros are? What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way of constructing of ioctl number is described at the top of the header [include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h#L88):

> ioctl command encoding: 32 bits total, command in lower 16 bits,
> size of the parameter structure in the lower 14 bits of the
> upper 16 bits.
>
> ...
>
> De facto, however, the top 8 bits of the lower 16
> bits are indeed used as a type field

That is, an ioctl number is constructed from 4 fields, from upper to lower:

1. `dir` - direction, 2 bits.

   - Upper bit denotes that a user writes an argument,
   - Lower bit denotes that a user reads an argument.
2. `size` - size of the argument, 14 bits.
3. `type` - a number uniquely representing a driver, 8 bit.
4. `nr` - a number which is unique for the type (for the driver), 8 bit.

For decode

```
#define IOCTL_MAGIC 'A'
#define IOCTL_NAME _IOWR(IOCTL_MAGIC, 2, ioctl_param)
```

you need to know the **size** of `ioctl_param` structure (`sizeof(ioctl_param)`).

E.g., if the size of the structure is 16 bytes, then ioctl fields are:

1. `dir` - 0x3 (both read and write).
2. `size` - 0x10 (size of the structure, 16).
3. `type` - 0x41 (ASCII code of the character `A`).
4. `nr` - 0x2 (the second argument).

and the ioctl number itself is 0xc0104102.